# How to eval/exec code in python without using exec or eval functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec, eval

I'm wondering how it would be possible to code a function that functions the same as eval or exec.

Say I wanted to execute python code within a python script here is a example:

```
x = 'print("Hello world")'
eval(x)
```

or

```
exec(x)
```

how could I execute this code replicating the functionality of eval or exec in this example, without
using any builtin functions.

Comment: This was the basic idea of the [PyPy](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/introduction.html) project. And it is rather complicated.

Comment: You basically have to write your own Python compiler.

Comment: Is there another function that produces similar functionality ?